# Is it ok to ask a new (related) question in the comments?

Tags: support, questions, comments, etiquette

The case is simple: I asked a question. It got answered with all the information requested. Then I realized a little bit more info would be handy. Should I ask for it in a comment to the accepted answer ? Thanks

Comment: if you ask for too much, you risk turning it into ["chameleon question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) which are not well appreciated by answerers

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking a new question but referring back to your other question to provide detailed context.  This way, each question (and its answers) stands on its own.

Answer (score 9):

If it is a new question, ask a new question.

As it is related to another question, a link to that question would be a good idea, adding information.

Hiding questions in comments is not good practice - people don't see them. We also don't like the practice of getting follow on questions in comments. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) about "chameleon questions".

Comment: I believe I didn't turn the topic into a chameleon question, but I'm sure it's useful to know the concept. Thanks to you and @gnat.

Comment: @fpessoa - If you need a small clarification on the answer, that's fine. The issue the community has is with question after question coming up (in particular when they start diverging from the original question).

Answer (score 7):

Depends on the amount of info.

If it's a teensy bit more info, no problem. Otherwise, it should be relevant to the question--by relevant I mean that it should be helpful to solving the question.

Basically, ask yourself "Would knowledge gleaned from answers to this comment help *solve the above question*?" If the answer's no, then ask it as a separate question.

Comment: The question solved the dilemma IMHO. Thanks

Comment: Excellent criterion.

Answer (score 4):

If the additional question is *only to clarify* a point made in the post then IMO that is fine.  However, if you are asked a question that could essentially stand by itself then you should *gently* nudge the OP to post a new question (if needed).  It all depends on the situation -

- How the additional question was asked

  - politely?
  - demanding?
  - etc...
- What the question is

  - a totally different subject?
  - a related subject?
  - etc...
- What mood/situation you find *yourself* in

  - already spend a substantial amount of time helping the OP?
  - enough battery life?
  - girlfriend is waiting for you to `Get off that damn computer!!`
  - etc...

There are no rules here and you will not be punished for answering those additional questions.

On the bright side you'll be helping someone and that is a **good thing** - its what we're here for

- Helping fellow programmers
- Making the internet a better place

---

I just realized that my answer was actually addressing the person who would be considering answering an additional question and not the asker.  In anycase I hope the points I made shed some light on the subject and possibly help you to understand what might be going on the mind of the people attempting to assist you.

Comment: It was indeed useful. Now I know how the guy who answered me at first might think about it. ;o) Thanks